# Why does `for...of` in Typescript copy the iterable object before looping?

Tags: javascript, typescript, for-of-loop

For example:

```
const aKeys = [];
for (let key of aKeys) {
...
}
```

Is transpiled to:

```
var aKeys = [];
for (var _i = 0, aKeys_1 = aKeys; _i < aKeys_1.length; _i++) {
    var key = aKeys_1[_i];
}
```

What's the point of `aKeys_1` here?

You can also view this live in Typescript playground [here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=const%20aKeys%20%3D%20%5B%5D%3B%0D%0Afor%20(let%20key%20of%20aKeys)%20%7B%0D%0A%7D).

Comment: because you used let instead of var

Comment: @toskv I thought something close, but try it in the playground. Not true.

Comment: @OmarAlshaker, because instead of `aKeys` the array could as well be `a.b.c.d("lorem ipsum").e[42]`. And here you might get into trouble if you don't cache the Array you're iterating over.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you could reassign `aKeys` in the loop body, and it should not affect the iteration. Of course it's not necessary when you *don't*, but the transpiler doesn't know for sure.

And in general, as @Thomas observed in the comments, the expression must be evaluated only once - while it's trivial to see that it won't make a difference for a reference to a `const` variable, in general it's not that easy.

Comment: I think it can know pretty easily by examining the loop's block, can it not? Or is it just not implemented because of reasons?

Comment: @MadaraUchiha It can be determined for *some* code blocks (but [not in general for all programs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem)). It would need to bail out when encountering `eval` somewhere, but also any function calls would need to be traced down for side effects etc. So, yeah, "reasons" - even if some simple cases should be trivial indeed. Like `aKeys` being declared as `const`. Uh.